# Adding a class to Vue child component from a parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that has few child components (inputs of the same type).
The number of inputs may vary and it depends on the user, But there is a requirement to have at least one input filled.
So, for example, I may have 5 inputs, 4 of them can be empty and it still considered valid.

My problem is that I want to add a red border around the first input in the list when all the inputs are empty.
I check the inputs on the parent component.

I have something like this in the parent component:

```
<template>
    <custom-input v-for="(input, key) in inputs_num" :key=key" />
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            inputValues: [],
            inputs_num: 1
        }
    }
    methods: {
        checkInputs() { 
            const validInputsCounter = 0;
            this.inputValues.forEach((input) => {
                if(input.trim().length > 4) validInputsCounter++;
            });

            if(validInputsCounter == 0) {
                // Add border to the first input in the list.
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
</script>
```

I couldn't figure out how should I set the border for the first input only.

Comment: That sounds like something you should handle in the child component. You could add something in compute (`allEmpty`) to track if all input fields are empty. Then you can pass bind your class with the red border if `allEmpty` is true (where this only appears on the first input): `v-bind:class="{ showRedBorder: allEmpty}"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend passing the highlight state as a prop on the child component.

```
<template>
    <custom-input v-for="(input, key) in inputs_num" :key=key" :highlight="higlightInput(key)"/>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            inputValues: [],
            inputs_num: 1
        }
    }
    methods: {
        highlightInput(key){
            if(key == 0){
                if(this.inputValues.find(i => i.trim().length > 4) != undefined){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then in your child component you declare a "highlight" prop with a default of "false".  Presumably have an `<input>` element in that template - you can apply the class like this:

```
<input type = "text" :class="{'red-border':highlight}" ... />
```

*Code not checked for validity.  Syntax error hunting is left as an exercise for the reader.*

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```html
<template>
    <custom-input v-for="key in inputValues.length" :key="key" v-model.trim="itemValues[key - 1]" :class="{red_border: key==1 && allEmpty}" />
</template>

<script>
export default
{
    data() {
        return {
            inputValues: [],
        }
    },
    computed:
    {
      allEmpty()
      {
        return !this.inputValues.some(item => (item || '').trim().length > 4);
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: OP indicated that this is their parent component, not the child component.

Comment: @GenericUser Are you saying that the child component `CustomInput` refers recursively to itself in its own template? If not - then what is wrong with the given parent component?